# Can not get RadioButton.selectedValue

Tags: java, flex4, typeerror

I am using `flex 4.0 an ZK framework` for a project.
I have 4 states and there are 3 radiobuttongroups in these states.
2 of them in the first, 1 of them in the 4th state.

My problem is,I can get the value of first 2 radiobuttongroups like this:

```
smthg.asdfg = DurumRadio.selectedValue.toString();
```

But when i try to do the same thing with the 3rd one which is in state 4, the component generated but its value becomes null and gives me this error in debug:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

Do yu have any idea ? Is it because of the state difference? I tried to change the state before.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try adding itemCreationPolicy="immediate" property to the radio button group at the 4.th state.

Comment: I couldn't do that Tolga? Radiobuttongroups must be declared in the declarations, but itemCreationPolicy cannot be declared in there. I am totally confused. This Flex is plain stupid. Thanks anyway...